# Best way to create an array will multiple objects generated the same way?

Tags: ruby

What more elegant way to do this in ruby way? I suppose this is good:

```
([0]*5).collect { Factory :customer_pj }
```

or

```
 (1..5).to_a.collect { Factory :customer_pj }
```

My goal is to initialize 5 customers and put into array. I happen to be doing this in a `let` in an rspec test.

Comment: Note that creating many objects in the database like this will inevitably make your tests very slow.

Comment: Ok, Im using DatabaseCleaner.clean, thanks for warning me about

Comment: Whether your cleaning or not is irrelevant, hitting the database is among the slowest thing you can do in a test, and doing it many times is that many times worse.

Comment: Its a good point for another question, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let(:customers) do
  Array.new(5){ Factory :customer_pj }
end
```

Since Andrew Marshall edited the question, the relevant part became this:

```
Array.new(5){ Factory :customer_pj }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
5.times.map { Factory :customer_pj }
```

Comment: Its great too! but means implicitly array creation, like my way. But your its more elegant.